# how to read packet from .pcap file without using any software

Tags: pcap, tcpdump, packet-capture

I captured packet using tcpdump -i {interface } -w file.pcap command and I want to read the packet in a human-readable language. how to do it?
How to read .pcap file just using shell script. Or suggest any alternative for it(without using any software)

Comment: The question is mostly unclear to me. First it is unclear what you mean with human-readable  here - is hex enough or what level of detail you want to be able to see? Second, what do you mean with *"without using any software"*? You propose a shell script - but this is already software. Thus, what software is allowed and what not?

Comment: You cannot read it without using software, even if it is as simple as software to print the bytes in the file as hex.  Your question makes no sense.

Comment: I never understand why people want to avoid using softwares.. how would you browse the internet without a browser ? A raw pcap is a blob of binary data. You could try parsing it yourself, but it's probably not what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

With tcpdump you can create a file with `-w`  .

But tcpdump can read this file with `-r` with many other display feature .

You can use `tcpflow` / `tshark` ( text tools ) to read the dump made by `tcpdump` .